# Hide marketing section on navigation in MS Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I would like to hide the marketing group in the navigation bar. I remove all the others privileges to the security role in order to hide the different entity but I can't hide the last one (my work > dashboards).[image: menu]

Is it possible to hide the marketing group via security roles and privileges ?

Do I have to change the SiteMap ?

Thank you for yor help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide it for all users (even for sysadmins) that the only answer is remove it from Sitemap.